# Create a Cloud Free Image, using BQA

Tags: google-earth-engine, cloud-cover

I am trying to create a cloud free image to use in the unsupervised classification, however my final product ("composite collection without cloud") stays with stranger stains and it seems to influence on the classification.
Does anyone know the reason for the stains, and how to soften them?

Link to my code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c18d6de5ada3e21a5b1aca9786efb103

Comment: QA layer isn't perfect. Cloud borders commonly aren't identified in this layer, this is why your image looks with stains. Fast solution? Line 70, change mosaic by median (`var composite_free_mosaic = composite_free.median();`) if you want to produce a single image, not a collection (as you said in the question). With median, you're avoiding high values produced by clouds in the final image

Comment: @aldo_tapia thank you for your help. Do you know how identify cloud borders, as you said the QA layer isn´t ok?

Comment: You can try an algorithm with thermal band + VIS, I've seen in some papers, but I don't remember right now

Comment: Thank you @aldo_tapia!